# database lock error sqlite android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, locked

I am receiving database is locked error in sqllite android. Is there anything wrong I am doing in my code ? I tried various stuff found from here, even tried to put thread sleep after I call query, but no use. I still get database locked error. Can anyone tell why I get that ? and what should I do to resolve this error ?

MainActivity class:

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class MapViewActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener,
        SensorEventListener, OnClickListener {

    GoogleMap googleMap;

    private boolean started = false;
    private ArrayList<AccelLocData> sensorData;
    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private Button btnStart, btnStop;
    private String provider;

    // File root, dir, sensorFile;
    FileOutputStream fOut;
    private Sensor mAccelerometer;
    private FileWriter writer;
    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    private BroadcastReceiver alarmReceiver;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntentSender, pendingIntentReceiver;

    private AlarmManager alarmManager;
    private Intent alarmIntent,alarmIntent2;

    // private Button btnUpload;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {

            databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
            databaseHelper.removeAll();


            Log.v("datacount",
                    Integer.toString(databaseHelper.getLocDataCount()));

            sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
            mAccelerometer = sensorManager
                    .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

            btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
            btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
            btnStart.setOnClickListener(this);
            btnStop.setOnClickListener(this);
            btnStart.setEnabled(true);
            btnStop.setEnabled(false);

            alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

            int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                    .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());
            if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) { // Google Play Services
                                                        // are
                                                        // not available

                int requestCode = 10;
                Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status,
                        this, requestCode);
                dialog.show();

            } else { // Google Play Services are available

                // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of
                // activity_main.xml
                // SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (MapFragment)
                // getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

                // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
                googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();


                // can use for overlay on the map
                List<Double> latList = new ArrayList<Double>();
                latList.add(145.7309593);
                latList.add(146.34);
                latList.add(147.34);

                List<Double> lonList = new ArrayList<Double>();
                lonList.add(-122.6365384);
                lonList.add(-123.6365384);
                lonList.add(-124.6365384);

                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    // LatLng latLng = new LatLng(45.7309593, -122.6365384);
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latList.get(i).doubleValue(),
                            lonList.get(i).doubleValue());
                    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                    googleMap
                            .addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                    .position(latLng)
                                    .title("My Spot")
                                    .snippet("This is my spot!")
                                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
                }

                // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
                googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
                Location location = locationManager
                        .getLastKnownLocation(provider);

                if (location != null) {
                    onLocationChanged(location);
                }

                locationManager
                        .requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        if (started) {

            double x = event.values[0];
            double y = event.values[1];
            double z = event.values[2];

            long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();

            LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_MEDIUM);
            criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);

            provider = locManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
            Location location = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            double latitude = 0;
            double longitude = 0;
            if (location != null) {
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
            }
            AccelLocData accelLocData = new AccelLocData(timestamp, x, y, z,
                    latitude, longitude);

            // Log.d("X data","data x:" + data.getX());

            try {
                // writer.write(data.toString());
                 if (databaseHelper != null)
                 databaseHelper.insertLocData(accelLocData);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        TextView tvLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_location);

        // Getting latitude of the current location
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();

        // Getting longitude of the current location
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();

        // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        // Showing the current location in Google Map
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        // Zoom in the Google Map
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));






    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnStart:

            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            alarmIntent = new Intent(context, AccelLocSender.class);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            pendingIntentSender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
                    alarmIntent, 0);

            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    System.currentTimeMillis(), 60000, pendingIntentSender);

            alarmIntent2 = new Intent(context, AccelLocReceiver.class);
            pendingIntentReceiver = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
                    alarmIntent2, 0);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    System.currentTimeMillis(), 30000, pendingIntentReceiver);

            btnStart.setEnabled(false);
            btnStop.setEnabled(true);
            Log.d("startbutton", "cam on click of start");
            started = true;

            // delete all files..
            // start thread to send data

            sensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer,
                    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
            break;
        case R.id.btnStop:
            try {
                btnStart.setEnabled(true);
                btnStop.setEnabled(false);
                // btnUpload.setEnabled(true);
                started = false;

                sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);

                Context context1 = getApplicationContext();
                AlarmManager alarmManager1 = (AlarmManager) context1
                        .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager1.cancel(pendingIntentSender);
                alarmManager1.cancel(pendingIntentReceiver);

            //  System.exit(0);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        /*
         * if (writer != null) { try { writer.close(); } catch (IOException e) {
         * // TODO Auto-generated catch block e.printStackTrace(); } }
         */
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        /*
         * try { Log.d("onresume","called onresume"); writer = new
         * FileWriter(sensorFile, true); } catch (IOException e) { // TODO
         * Auto-generated catch block e.printStackTrace(); }
         */
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

AccelLocSender.java

```
public class AccelLocSender extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    private static int indexValue=1;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("cmg in AccelLocsender");
        Log.i("Alarm sender", "Came in alarm sender");

        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);

        sendDataToServer();

    }

    private void sendDataToServer() {

        try {


            int locDataCount = databaseHelper.getLocDataCount();

            List<AccelLocData> accelLocDataList = databaseHelper.getAllDataById(indexValue);
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            databaseHelper.deleteLocDataById(indexValue);
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            indexValue += 50;

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("*****");

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            Log.d("datacount", Integer.toString(locDataCount));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("datacount", Integer
                    .toString(locDataCount)));
            for (int i = 0; i < accelLocDataList.size(); i++) {

                nameValuePairs
                        .add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude" + i,
                                Double.toString(accelLocDataList.get(i)
                                        .getLatitude())));
                nameValuePairs
                        .add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude" + i, Double
                                .toString(accelLocDataList.get(i)
                                        .getLongitude())));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("accelX" + i, Double
                        .toString(accelLocDataList.get(i).getX())));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("accelY" + i, Double
                        .toString(accelLocDataList.get(i).getY())));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("accelZ" + i, Double
                        .toString(accelLocDataList.get(i).getZ())));
                nameValuePairs
                        .add(new BasicNameValuePair("timeStamp" + i, Double
                                .toString(accelLocDataList.get(i)
                                        .getTimeStamp())));

            }

            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

DatabaseHelper.java

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "myapp.db";
    static String TABLE_NAME = "AccelLocation";

    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String LATITUDE_VAL = "latitude";
    private static final String LONGITUDE_VAL = "longitude";
    private static final String ACCEL_X = "accelX";
    private static final String ACCEL_Y = "accelY";
    private static final String ACCEL_Z = "accelZ";
    private static final String CUR_TIME = "dataTime";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 3);
    }

    SQLiteDatabase db;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        System.out.println("cmg in database helper");
        String CREATE_TABLE_SQL = "create table if not exists " + TABLE_NAME
                + " (" + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement,"
                + LATITUDE_VAL + " TEXT," + LONGITUDE_VAL + " TEXT," + ACCEL_X
                + " TEXT," + ACCEL_Y + " TEXT," + ACCEL_Z + " TEXT," + CUR_TIME
                + " TEXT" + ")";
        Log.d("createquery", CREATE_TABLE_SQL);
        System.out.println("Create query :" + CREATE_TABLE_SQL);
        // db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+TABLE_NAME);

        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_SQL);
    //  db.close();
    }

    public void insertLocData(AccelLocData accelLocData) {

        if(db == null)
        {
            db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        }

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(LATITUDE_VAL, accelLocData.getLatitude());
        values.put(LONGITUDE_VAL, accelLocData.getLongitude());
        values.put(ACCEL_X, accelLocData.getX());
        values.put(ACCEL_Y, accelLocData.getY());
        values.put(ACCEL_Z, accelLocData.getZ());
        values.put(CUR_TIME, accelLocData.getTimeStamp());

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    //  db.close(); // Closing database connection

    }

    public void dropTable(){
        if( db == null){
            db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        }

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    }
    public List<AccelLocData> getAllData() {

        Cursor cursor = null;

        List<AccelLocData> accelLocDataList = new ArrayList<AccelLocData>();
        //SQLiteDatabase db = null;
        // Select All Query
        try {

            String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
            if(db == null){
                db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            }

            cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

            // looping through all rows and adding to list
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    AccelLocData accelLocData = new AccelLocData(
                            Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                            Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(6)),
                            Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(3)),
                            Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(4)),
                            Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(5)),
                            Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(1)),
                            Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(2)));
                    accelLocDataList.add(accelLocData);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("DatabasegetallData", e.toString());
        } finally {
            if(cursor!= null)
            cursor.close();

    //      if(db!=null)
    //      db.close();


        }

        // return accelLocData list
        return accelLocDataList;

    }

    public List<AccelLocData> getAllDataById(int indexValue) {

        Cursor cursor = null;

        List<AccelLocData> accelLocDataList = new ArrayList<AccelLocData>();
    //  SQLiteDatabase db = null;
        // Select All Query
        try {
            String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " where "+ KEY_ID + " < "+ indexValue;

            if(db == null){
                db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            }
            cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

            // looping through all rows and adding to list
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    AccelLocData accelLocData = new AccelLocData(
                            Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                            Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(6)),
                            Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(3)),
                            Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(4)),
                            Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(5)),
                            Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(1)),
                            Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(2)));
                    accelLocDataList.add(accelLocData);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("DatabasegetallData", e.toString());
        } finally {
            if(cursor!= null)
            cursor.close();

        //  if(db!=null)
        //  db.close();


        }

        // return accelLocData list
        return accelLocDataList;

    }

    // Deleting single accelLocData
    public void deleteLocData(AccelLocData accelLocData) {
        if( db == null){
            db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        }

        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(accelLocData.getId()) });
    //  db.close();
    }

    public void deleteLocDataById(int indexValue) {
        if(db == null){
            db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        }
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, KEY_ID + " < ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(indexValue) });

    //  if(db != null)
    //  db.close();
    }

    // Getting contacts Count
    public int getLocDataCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        if (db == null){
            db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        }
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        int noOfRows = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
    //  db.close();
        return noOfRows;
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void removeAll() {

        if(db == null)
        db = this.getWritableDatabase(); // helper is object
                                                        // extends
                                                        // SQLiteOpenHelper
        db.delete(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, null);
    //  db.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: onSensorChanged fires way too rapidly always blocking other transactions to your database

Comment: @JRowan , my bad.. I pasted wrong code. Just updated code again. I am using DELAY_UI for sensor which is comparatively slow. But still i get database lock issue.

Comment: still accellerometer fires lightning fast every time its using your database

Comment: @JRowan what should I do for it ? Is there any solution for it other than making it to SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL which takes 200 mseconds.. ?

Comment: you could try making static boolean in database helper class and use while loops to make transactions when its not being used like after database close() toggle boolean to true, im not sure this is just an opinion

Comment: im not too good with this, but maybe synchronized threading could solve it, if you look into that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try declaring a reentrantlock in your database helper and lock and unlock everywhere you access your database.  This should allow threads to wait for database availability and avoid a crash/error.
e.g. In Database Helper:

```
    public static Lock l = new ReentrantLock(false);
```

Everywhere you access the database:

```
    l.lock();
    try
    {
           //do database editing
    }
    finally
    {
          l.unlock();
    }
```

However as previously mentioned, if you try to write to the database more times per second than your database edit can actually complete you will end up with a long backlog of database writes.  My suggestion would be to use a timestamp comparrison everytime the trigger for your database writing occurs and skip writing to the database unless it has been, for example, half a second since you last wrote that information to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you receive new onSensorData more often than the time it takes to store data in the db you will need to either speed up db writes in some way or skip events. Here's some thoughts off the top of my head.

Regarding speeding up db writes, you can probably assume that the location provider doesn't change between each event and if you think about what's likely to change and how often you can store certain things as member variables instead of retrieving them each time.

One way of skipping events is a rotating list. onSensorData add a new event to the end list and if it's above a certain length it removes the first(oldest) element. The db writer(possibly a thread) reads from the start of the list and writes the currently oldest element. If you use threads for this it'll need a bit of synchronisation though, to reduce synchronisation you can read events in batches instead of one at a time.

Or you can combine the two methods.

Comment: I did not get you. Could you please give me something with example or tell me something in my code ?